# PublicForTests annotation in MSTest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mstest

As I know, in `JUnit` I can set `@PublicForTests` annotation for logic tests.
I tried to find alternative in `MSTest` with no success.

What I'v found is people who said that I don't need to test private methods.
What is my alternative to check my logic of private methods?

Comment: You can test the public method which uses the private method.

Comment: Yeah... I know. but can't I test my private method? only with reflection?

Comment: Yeah, reflection would seem like your only alternative

Comment: Ok thanks. So that's that answer? write it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our comments, there are 2 main approaches that you can take to test private methods:

- The first is to indirectly test your private method via the public method that uses it.
- The second is to directly test your private method via Reflection.